# How do I make a header element's width goes to left slowly

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a hamburger side menu and header element and when I click that hamburger menu I want the header to be displayed initial and the header's width grows slowly to left how do I do that.

```css
header {
  width: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  top: 22px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>.</header>
<div id="main">
  <div class="hamburger"></div>
  <div class="hamburger"></div>
  <div class="hamburger"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [css transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to animate when `header` width goes from `0 to 100%`

```js
document.getElementById('main').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('header').classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header.show {
  width: 100%;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  top: 22px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div style="padding: 1em;">
    header
  </div>
</header>
<div id="main">
  <div class="hamburger"></div>
  <div class="hamburger"></div>
  <div class="hamburger"></div>
</div>
```